# how to import multiple s3 bucket resources to single terraform resource name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to import existing s3 buckets to my terraform code. i have a lot of buckets in the s3 so I want to collect under a single resource name. For example, let's consider 3 baskets running on s3, 2 of them are created with terraform but 1 of them is not created with terraform.

- terraformed-bucket
- terraformed-bucket-2
- nonterraformed-bucket

I have one resource name for these two buckets. I want to import **nonterraformed-bucket** to existing resource name that used for terraformed-buckets when migrating to terraform code. but i cant :/

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "tfer--buckets" {
  count         = "${length(var.bucket_names)}"
  bucket        = "${element(var.bucket_names, count.index)}"

  # count         = length(local.bucket_names)
  # bucket        = local.bucket_names[count.index]
  force_destroy = "false"

  grant {
    id          = "674f4d195ff567a2eeb7ee328c84410b02484f646c5f1f595f83ecaf5cfbf"
    permissions = ["FULL_CONTROL"]
    type        = "CanonicalUser"
  }

  object_lock_enabled = "false"
  request_payer       = "BucketOwner"

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm = "AES256"
      }

      bucket_key_enabled = "true"
    }
  }

  versioning {
    enabled    = "false"
    mfa_delete = "false"
  }
}
```

and my variables:

```
variable "bucket_names" {
  type    = list
  default = ["terraformed-bucket", "terraformed-bucket-2"]
}
```

these are the states in my terraform code

```
mek-bash@%: terraform state list
aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[0]
aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[1]
```

i tried to import **nonterraformed-bucket** to existing this resource:

> resource "aws_s3_bucket" "tfer--buckets" {}

with this command:
`terraform import aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets nonterraformed-bucket`

but still the output of **terraform state list** is the same. nothing changed:

```
mek-bash@%: terraform import aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets nonterraformed-bucket 

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.

mek-bash@%: terraform state list                                       
aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[0]
aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[1]
```

I don't want to use separate resources for each bucket. So I want to import each outside bucket with the same name as the others. So I want to include it as [2] in the same resource name. justlike:

```
mek-bash@%: terraform state list
aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[0]
aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[1]
aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[2] (should represent nonterraformed-bucket)
```

Do you have any suggestions for this? Or is there a way to import non-terraformed resources into a single resource name?

Comment: I think you would first need to add the name of the bucket created outside of terraform into the list of bucket names. Then, since you are using `count` to create multiple buckets, you would have to use the syntax for importing resources creted with `count`, e.g., `terraform import 'aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[2]' nonterraformed-bucket`. You might also have issues with import due to the naming convention you use for the resource `tfer--buckets`, as it is not really following the best practices.

Comment: Great! It worked with 
`terraform import 'aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[2]' nonterraformed-bucket `

it fixed after quotes *'aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[2]'* . 

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with:

> terraform import 'aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[2]' nonterraformed-bucket

it fixed after quotes **'aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[2]'**

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your your `nonterraformed-bucket` into `bucket_names`:

```
variable "bucket_names" {
  type    = list
  default = ["terraformed-bucket", "terraformed-bucket-2", "nonterraformed-bucket"]
}
```

and then import it as `[2]` (third bucket):

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[2] nonterraformed-bucket
```

Comment: actually i tried this but it didnt work. 

mek-bash@%: terraform import aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[2]   nonterraformed-bucket
*zsh: no matches found: aws_s3_bucket.tfer--buckets[2]*

Comment: @memrekaraaslan You have double check your TF code and whether the buckets actually exist and are called as you think they are.

Comment: i checked twice Marcin. i also changed my bucket name from *tfer--buckets* to *buckets* . Tha main problem here is i can not import nonterraformed-bucket to an already used resource_name.  Also i cannot use list [] in the import command:
`no matches found: aws_s3_bucket.buckets[1]`